# How to restrict some Networking Modes in Oracle VirtualBox VM?

Tags: networking, virtualbox, virtual-machine

Network administrators are indicating the firewall policies (AD based) are being bypassed in the [Bridged networking](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html#network_bridged) representing a security risk.

Is there a way (via Registry Settings for example) network administrators can restrict the use of some of the Networking Modes? This way, users won't be able to select the "risky" network settings.

Answer (score 0):

I got an answer after [posting this question](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=103524&sid=013fc8745c321f1324647d2c7e1188b0) in the VirtualBox forum: [According to the documentation](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch02.html), the `ADDLOCAL` installer parameter allows to explicitly name the features to be installed, in my case, avoid passing the `VBoxNetworkFlt` value for the unattended installation:

```
msiexec /i VirtualBox-<version>-Win.msi ADDLOCAL=VBoxApplication,VBoxUSB
```

For interactive installation, the parameter just show this feature not selected by default:

```
VirtualBox.exe -msiparams ADDLOCAL=VBoxApplication,VBoxUSB
```